# Qual é o uso do 'SELECT 1'?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou fazendo uma consulta usando o NOT EXISTS em um trabalho da faculdade. A situação é a seguinte:

1.14 - Projetar o CPF e o valor a pagar em aluguéis por clientes que alugaram mídias e ainda não efetuaram nenhum pagamento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A consulta realizada e que deu certo, segue abaixo:

```
SELECT A.CPF_Cliente, 
       SUM(ValorPagar) AS TotalValorPagar
FROM   Aluguel A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM  Pagamentos B 
                   WHERE  A.CPF_Cliente = B.CPF_Cliente 
                          AND A.ID_Midia = B.ID_Midia 
                          AND A.DataLocacao = B.DataLocacao) 
GROUP  BY A.CPF_Cliente;
```

Pesquisando sobre como utilizar o `NOT EXISTS`, verifiquei que em vários exemplos utilizavam o `SELECT 1`. Gostaria de saber como ele funciona e onde devo utilizá-lo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que seja pra *"não"* trazer os resultado pro *"retorno"*, como no caso é uma *sub-query* então você não precisaria definir nenhuma coluna, mas ainda sim é necessário escrever algo.

Costumamos fazer isto quando vamos contar registros:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tabela
```

Se tiver uma tabela assim:

```
 id | nome   |
  1 | João   |
  2 | Maria  |
  3 | Pedro  |
```

E executar isto `SELECT nome FROM tabela` retorna:

```
João
Maria
Pedro
```

Retornou um total de 14 caracteres

E isto `SELECT 1 FROM tabela` retorna:

```
1
1
1
```

Retornou um total de 3 caracteres, acredito que este seja o motivo principal **"tentar"** conseguir uma melhor performance.

Comment: Gostei da resposta. Apesar de que fazendo uma rápida pesquisa aqui, verifiquei que realizados alguns testes usando o SELECT 1 e o SELECT * em subqueries, não deu muita diferença em performance.Mas respondeu bem o que eu queria saber, obrigado!

Comment: @williamhk2 por isto escrevi o **"tentar"**, isto pode ser apenas sentido quando você tiver um numero muito alto de registros. No entanto hoje a maioria dos motores de banco tem técnicas de optimização :)

Comment: boa Guilherme, valeu!

Comment: Basicamente vai retornar os valores existentes, como se fosse "SELECT true FROM tabela", é trabalho direito com `booleano` num query, e não é recomendado.

Comment: Desculpe, eu não sei se é recomendado ou não @Edilson, poderia citar alguma fonte, apenas por curiosidade. Obrigado

Comment: Porque basicamente vai selecionar tudo, que possua um valor qualquer. Por isso tem casos próprios para se usar. Apesar de não ser um exemplo relacionado à pergunta atual, imagina, uma tabela `usuarios` com um campo `usuario` com propriedade `unique`, e executamos uma consulta, `update usuarios set usuario = 'teste' where true`. Para essa consulta vai falhar, porque o campo `usuario` possui referência única, mas para uma consulta do tipo select, ela retornaria verdadeiro para todo e qualquer valor nela existente.

Comment: @Edilson você esta invertendo a lógica, me desculpe, mas o caso aqui não é com `WHERE` e sim com `SELECT`. Acho que são duas situações bem diferentes e a pergunta aqui fala sobre o 1 no SELECT e não no WHERE. Acredito que o seu comentário seria apenas um adicional ao uso do 1 mas não é ligado a situação :)

Comment: Tá bem, mas é bem sabido que que uma coisa leva a  outra, foi essa uma das razões para eu ter feito referência a isso. Embora eu não tenha inventado lógica nenhuma, é bem verdade que são situações diferentes, apesar de eu já ter citado isto também no outro comentário.

Comment: @Edilson eu me referia a lógica da pergunta e não do código :)

Comment: Também é muito utilizado em um `EXISTS`. Exemplo: `WHERE
 EXISTS( SELECT 
            1
        FROM
            customers
        WHERE id > 1)`. Justamente comentado acima, performance.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos ver essa parte da SQL:

```
               FROM  Pagamentos B 
               WHERE  A.CPF_Cliente = B.CPF_Cliente 
                      AND A.ID_Midia = B.ID_Midia 
                      AND A.DataLocacao = B.DataLocacao
```

Isso daí vai trazer algum número de registros (`EXISTS`) se houver algum lugar aonde essas condições do `WHERE` forem satisfeitas e nenhum registo (`NOT EXISTS`) se não houver nenhum lugar aonde elas são satisfeitas.

A única informação relevante no ponto é se o MySQL achou alguma coisa ou não. O conteúdo exato das tuplas encontradas é irrelevante. No entanto, a cláusula `SELECT` deve trazer pelo menos uma coluna com informações. Dado que nenhuma das colunas é relevante, você poderia optar por colocar quaisquer conjuntos de colunas nesse `SELECT`, mas o conjunto de colunas mais interessante seria aquele que forçasse o MySQL a olhar para o menor número possível de colunas ao montar o resultado. Esse menor número possível de colunas é zero, e portanto o `SELECT` não deveria ter nenhuma das colunas do resultado. Entretanto, como o `SELECT` precisa ter alguma coisa, a solução é colocar o `SELECT 1`, que trás uma constante simples e de peso negligível no resultado.

Comment: Demorei a entender, mas gostei da resposta. Apesar de que fazendo uma rápida pesquisa aqui, verifiquei que realizados alguns testes usando o SELECT 1 e o SELECT * em subqueries, não deu muita diferença em performance. Mas respondeu bem o que eu queria saber, obrigado!